# Remove dimensions from filename featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I have a problem with a featured image. It's a gif, but when I add it, Wordpress adds the dimensions to the filename, which breaks the gif (since then it's not really a gif anymore).

Is there a way to disable the addition of dimensions to the filename for only the featured image?

The link to my image is:
`http://whatweblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/hue.gif`
The link to my image after selecting it as a featured image is: `http://whatweblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/hue-620x349.gif`

I guess Wordpress is making a thumbnail of my image, but I don't want and need that, since I want the gif to be moving and on the front page.

I remember having no problem at all with this in [the past](http://whatweblog.com/the-ark/), but now Wordpress adds the dimensions, breaking the GIF in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to creating additional dimension, Wordpress does keep your original image. Your original image is in this link `http://whatweblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/hue.gif`

So, instead of stopping Wordpress from creating additional dimension, you should retrieve the full image when displaying the featured image. You can get the full image with this -

```
the_post_thumbnail('full');
```

In your case, change

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-image', array('class' => 'featured-full-width-top')); ?>
```

to

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'featured-full-width-top')); ?>
```

**Remove Thumbnail Generation**

See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91170/23214

> Another easier option I think works is going to your Settings-->Media and setting each box for width and height to 0

Comment: I found out by using the EXACT dimensions (350 instead of 349 high) the GIF works fine. But still want to prevent this from happening. Do I have to replace `<?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-image', array('class' => 'featured-full-width-top')); ?>` with `<?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-image', array('class' => 'full')); ?>`?

Comment: @Rvervuurt See my edit

Comment: I don't really know what kind of result the media-setting has on other stuff, so I just changed the `php`-part. Thanks!