# Upload multiple files

Tags: uploads, forms

I added this code but when I upload 1 image, then 4 images of 1 image are uploaded, what is happening

IMAGES : **Not proper working**

PDF file upload : **work fine**

Doc file upload : **work fine**

rvt file upload : **not working**

Now I am trying to upload multiple files my HTML code is:

```
<input type="file" name="my_file_upload[]" id="my_file_upload[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Code > file custom.php

```
if ( $_FILES ) { 
$files = $_FILES["my_file_upload"];  
foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {            
        if ($files['name'][$key]) { 
            $file = array( 
                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                'type' => $files['type'][$key], 
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key], 
                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
            ); 
            $_FILES = array ("my_file_upload" => $file); 
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {              
                $newupload = my_handle_attachment($file,$pid); 
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Function.php File code

```
function my_handle_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$set_thu=false) {
// check to make sure its a successful upload
if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

 require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
 require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
 require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

 $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );
if ( is_numeric( $attach_id ) ) {
  update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_file_upload', $attach_id );
 }
return $attach_id;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the RVT that's because WordPress restricts the set of file types you're allowed to upload. You'll need to add it to the [upload_mimes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_mimes/) filter. Do all of these files work when uploading them individually?

Comment: @Rup thx  but  when I upload 1 image, then 4 images of 1 image are uploaded, what is happening

Comment: Oh, sorry, misunderstood what you were asking. One of them is your original upload, and the other four are different sizes generated by WordPress: usually there's thumbnail (150px largest dimension), medium (300px), medium large (768px) and large (1024px). If you look at the full filename it should identify the sizes it's used.

Comment: You'll also notice that the filesize is drastically different. The second file is only 4KB, while your original is probably 80KB. [You can disable this behaviour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91166/how-to-disable-wordpress-from-creating-thumbnails), but do so with care.

Comment: @kero thx sir one more question can yo help me

Comment: @Rup Thx sir   sir one more question can yo help me

Comment: Plz check > https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/382456/drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax-wordpress