# Drag and drop multiple file upload using Ajax WordPress

Tags: ajax, javascript, jquery

How can i upload multiple files via drag & drop and browse with ajax.

But I select and upload the file, it works. But when I drag & drop, Ajax's error is coming.

[image]

[image]

**My HTML Code here.**

```
      <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">
                      <div id="drag_upload_file">
                          <img src="<?php echo plugins_url("../images/dragImg/",__FILE__) ?>dragimg.png" alt="" />
                          <p><input type="button" value="Choose a file or drag you files here." onclick="file_explorer();"></p>
                          <input type="file" name="my_file_upload[]" id="selectfile" multiple="multiple">
                          
                        
           </div>
          </div>
```

**JavaScript code.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 var fileobj;

  function upload_file(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        for (i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.files.length; i++)
        {
            fileobj = e.dataTransfer.files[i];
            ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
        }
    }

      function file_explorer() {
        document.getElementById('selectfile').click();
        document.getElementById('selectfile').onchange = function() {
          //here you can get all files
          for (var i=0; i< e.dataTransfer.files.length;i++){
              fileobj = document.getElementById('selectfile').files[i];
              ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
          }
        };
     }
   
  function ajax_file_upload(file_obj) {
      if(file_obj != undefined) {
          var form_data = new FormData();
          for(i=0; i<file_obj.length; i++) {  
              form_data.append('file[]', file_obj[i]);  
          }
          jQuery.ajax({
              method : 'POST',
              url : order_process_ajax_object.ajax_url,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              data: form_data,
              success:function(response) {
                  alert(response);
                  jQuery('#selectfile').val('');
              }
          });
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please also add the PHP code you have hooked to wp_ajax, so that people can help to debug - 400 error could indicate that you are missing an Ajax handler or that it is not placed or hooked correctly.

Comment: You need to set an 'action' value in the POST too, to match the name you used with wp_ajax_<name> and wp_ajax_noprov_<name>.

Comment: @Rup thanx sir one more jQuery question can u plz help me if you dont mind

Comment: OK, sure. Another part of this question or a new question? I can't find it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at your answer carefully before it got deleted. Perhaps you could post it as a new question? But it looked like you'd commented out the code to remove the active class, so you weren't removing it, and I don't understand what you were doing with the class-1234 classes.